# Free Java API for scanning fingerprints

Tags: gratis, java, api, authentication

Is there any free Java API available for scanning fingerprints?

I want to implement fingerprint functionality in a web application which will scan and identify the fingerprint based on available fingerprint in data store. If not available it will store as new.

Comment: What scanner hardware?

Comment: I dont have knowledge about hardware like which are the best hardware is available